# Stop and Resume Activity when get Incoming calls in Android

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I have a query regarding `Phonestatelistener` in `Android`.
 Scenario is I have made a quiz App.
 Everything is working fine but when I get any incoming call, my quiz does not stop.
I want it stop and resume after end of phone call.

I have used `PhoneStateListener` for that purpose but don't know how to call `onStop()` and `onResume()` for `Activity`.
Here is the code I am using:

```
PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {  
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {  
        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){  

        }  

        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone is Currently in A call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }  

        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"phone is neither ringing nor in a call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }  
    }  
};

tManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not call `onStop()`, `onResume()`, etc. Android does. You should have code in those methods to handle the state of your quiz. Also you may be interested in the `onWIndowFocusChanged()` callback method (also called by Android).

Comment: Sorry sir couldn't get you!! Android will stop Activity itself when in RINGING state??

Comment: @Karakuri: Any specific reason that you mentioned to use onWindowFocusChanged(). I think onStart() -> onStop() are enough to do this job

Comment: Working on it. Will let you know for sure when done.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to call phone listener. when any phone comes android automatically call **onPause()** and **onStop()** method. you have to only override the method and stop your timer in ***onPause()*** and resume it ***onResume()*** method.